# Laravel not able to pass more than 1 return - how can that be done using similar method?

Tags: ajax, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5, controller

I have a small problem with redirecting a user once page is created.

Problem is that all together I have 3 returns within 2 functions and obviously that can't be done and I am looking for a way to change this but I don't know what should it be.

Process is like this.

User creates a page: code is saved into javascript variable.
User chooses a name for a page: code is saved into another javascript variable.

Ajax is passing these values to Controller and then:

```
 public function postDB(Request $request) {
    $newName = $request->input('name_website');
    $newLat = $request->input('newCode');
    $websites = new Website();
    $websites->name = $newName;
    $websites->html = $newLat;
    $websites->save();
    return $newName;
    return $this->website($newName);
}
   public function website($newName)
{
    dd($newName);
    Website::where('name', $newName)->first()->html;
    return view('layouts/website');
}
```

After saving into a database I am returning value of $newName which is the actual name for a website or I should say URL and also return (call another function) which then search for html code that matches a name, and return view that deals with displaying it:

```
@extends('layouts.master') @section('title', 'Website Builder') @section('content')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />


{{html_entity_decode($name->html)}}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    axios.get('/name').then(
        html => document.querySelector('html').innerHTML = html     
    );
</script>
</html>
@endsection @show
```

So basically after user saved it to database I want to redirect them to a page which is in saved variable $newName and retrieve + display html that matches name that is in the variable.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('home', 'BuilderController@homepage');
    Route::get('template', 'BuilderController@templates');
    Route::post('template', 'BuilderController@postDB');
    Route::get('logout', 'BuilderController@getLogout');
    Route::get('/{name}', 'BuilderController@website');
});
```

template.blade.php

```
<button onClick=" updateDatabase(this);" type="button" class="form-control margin btn btn-success" id="getRequest changes">
                    Save Website
                </button>
```

JS:

```
var web_name;
function updateDatabase(newCode, name_website)
{
    code2 = document.getElementById("content-link2").innerHTML;
    web_name = ($('#website_name').val());
    // make an ajax request to a PHP file
    // on our site that will update the database
    // pass in our lat/lng as parameters
    $.post('http://localhost/template', {
            _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
            newCode: (code2),
            name_website: (web_name),
        })
        .done(function() {
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
}
```

EDIT: I have update my code like I was told in the answer below but now I am getting:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\fyproject\resources\views\layouts\website.blade.php)
in 87bb9cbe60b5bd1fe6f78e1246f2227dbd0f328f.php line 5
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\xampp\htdocs\fyproject\storage\framework\views/87bb9cbe60b5bd1fe6f78e1246f2227dbd0f328f.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'name' => ' <title>Template 1</title> <link href="http://localhost/templates/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <div class="logo"> <img class="images" id="image" src="#" alt="Your Logo"> </div> <div contenteditable="true" id="content" class="draggable ui-widget-content refresh ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative; left: 209px; top: 139px;"><p>Change Text inside this box</p></div> <div id="editTxt" class="refresh" contenteditable="true"> <p>This text can be by the user.</p> </div> ')) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\xampp\htdocs\fyproject\resources\views/layouts/website.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'name' => ' <title>Template 1</title> <link href="http://localhost/templates/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <div class="logo"> <img class="images" id="image" src="#" alt="Your Logo"> </div> <div contenteditable="true" id="content" class="draggable ui-widget-content refresh ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative; left: 209px; top: 139px;"><p>Change Text inside this box</p></div> <div id="editTxt" class="refresh" contenteditable="true"> <p>This text can be by the user.</p> </div> ')) in View.php line 149
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
public function postDB(Request $request) {
    $newName = $request->input('name_website');
    $newLat = $request->input('newCode');
    $websites = new Website();
    $websites->name = $newName;
    $websites->html = $newLat;
    $websites->save();

    // Now we go to our other function
    $this->website($newName);
}

public function website($newName)
{
    // Return our "website" object
    $website = Website::where('name', $newName)->first();

    // Pass the contents of the "html" property to the view
    return view('layouts/website', [
        'html' => $website->html
    );
}
```

This will give you access to the content of your "html" attribute in your blade template as `$html`.

#### Edit

If you are using your controller for an API you might consider not returning a view but instead a json response which you can listen for:

```
return response()->json([
        'url'  => $website->name,
        'html' => $website->html
]);
```

You can then handle the content of the page or redirect using javascript

Comment: Have a look at my code above, at the view that is dealing with because I've got a feeling that something is wrong with it. When I click on save, I still do not get redirected but I don't get any error message

Comment: Where is it that you are clicking on "save"? I can't see any `<button>`, `<input>` or `<a>` tags in the markup you have provided. I can only help with what i can see!

Comment: any guess? I am still stuck on it

Comment: Sorry, just drove home. Having a look now.

Comment: Sure no problem

Comment: Your property of  non-object error will likely be `$name->html` in `website.blade.php`. Hopefully all you should need to do is just replace it with `$html` to get rid of that error

Comment: unfortunately same error message :( I will never get this done, and yeah it's exactly that line of code that causes errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135413/discussion-between-spholt-and-przemek).

Comment: you can't have 2 returns in 1 function!